# display json canvas image from php on page load

Tags: php, html, json, canvas

I am trying to recreate a signature in a canvas when the page loads.
I have managed to capture a signature and store it in a MySQL database using PHP. It is stored as json data.
Now the problem is this:
I have a page with a canvas element and I can retrieve the json data from the database before the page loads using php but I do not know how to pass this data to the canvas element.
Hoping for a solution because I have spent too many hours messing this up.
Thank you!

json data:

```
"[
   {
      \"lx\":87,
      \"ly\":6,
      \"mx\":87,
      \"my\":5
   },
   {
      \"lx\":88,
      \"ly\":5,
      \"mx\":87,
      \"my\":6
   },
   {
      \"lx\":89,
      \"ly\":6,
      \"mx\":88,
      \"my\":5
   },
   {
      \"lx\":89,
      \"ly\":7,
      \"mx\":89,
      \"my\":6
   },
   {
      \"lx\":90,
      \"ly\":7,
      \"mx\":89,
      \"my\":7
   },
   {
      \"lx\":90,
      \"ly\":8,
      \"mx\":90,
      \"my\":7
   },
   {
      \"lx\":90,
      \"ly\":10,
      \"mx\":90,
      \"my\":8
   },
   {
      \"lx\":91,
      \"ly\":11,
      \"mx\":90,
      \"my\":10
   },
   {
      \"lx\":92,
      \"ly\":11,
      \"mx\":91,
      \"my\":11
   },
   {
      \"lx\":92,
      \"ly\":12,
      \"mx\":92,
      \"my\":11
   },
   {
      \"lx\":93,
      \"ly\":12,
      \"mx\":92,
      \"my\":12
   },
   {
      \"lx\":93,
      \"ly\":13,
      \"mx\":93,
      \"my\":12
   },
   {
      \"lx\":95,
      \"ly\":15,
      \"mx\":93,
      \"my\":13
   },
   {
      \"lx\":96,
      \"ly\":16,
      \"mx\":95,
      \"my\":15
   },
   {
      \"lx\":97,
      \"ly\":16,
      \"mx\":96,
      \"my\":16
   },
   {
      \"lx\":97,
      \"ly\":17,
      \"mx\":97,
      \"my\":16
   },
   {
      \"lx\":98,
      \"ly\":18,
      \"mx\":97,
      \"my\":17
   },
   {
      \"lx\":99,
      \"ly\":18,
      \"mx\":98,
      \"my\":18
   },
   {
      \"lx\":99,
      \"ly\":19,
      \"mx\":99,
      \"my\":18
   },
   {
      \"lx\":99,
      \"ly\":20,
      \"mx\":99,
      \"my\":19
   },
   {
      \"lx\":102,
      \"ly\":5,
      \"mx\":102,
      \"my\":4
   },
   {
      \"lx\":101,
      \"ly\":5,
      \"mx\":102,
      \"my\":5
   },
   {
      \"lx\":101,
      \"ly\":6,
      \"mx\":101,
      \"my\":5
   },
   {
      \"lx\":100,
      \"ly\":7,
      \"mx\":101,
      \"my\":6
   },
   {
      \"lx\":100,
      \"ly\":8,
      \"mx\":100,
      \"my\":7
   },
   {
      \"lx\":99,
      \"ly\":8,
      \"mx\":100,
      \"my\":8
   },
   {
      \"lx\":99,
      \"ly\":9,
      \"mx\":99,
      \"my\":8
   },
   {
      \"lx\":98,
      \"ly\":9,
      \"mx\":99,
      \"my\":9
   },
   {
      \"lx\":98,
      \"ly\":10,
      \"mx\":98,
      \"my\":9
   },
   {
      \"lx\":97,
      \"ly\":11,
      \"mx\":98,
      \"my\":10
   },
   {
      \"lx\":96,
      \"ly\":12,
      \"mx\":97,
      \"my\":11
   },
   {
      \"lx\":95,
      \"ly\":12,
      \"mx\":96,
      \"my\":12
   },
   {
      \"lx\":94,
      \"ly\":12,
      \"mx\":95,
      \"my\":12
   },
   {
      \"lx\":93,
      \"ly\":12,
      \"mx\":94,
      \"my\":12
   },
   {
      \"lx\":91,
      \"ly\":13,
      \"mx\":93,
      \"my\":12
   },
   {
      \"lx\":89,
      \"ly\":14,
      \"mx\":91,
      \"my\":13
   },
   {
      \"lx\":89,
      \"ly\":15,
      \"mx\":89,
      \"my\":14
   },
   {
      \"lx\":88,
      \"ly\":15,
      \"mx\":89,
      \"my\":15
   },
   {
      \"lx\":87,
      \"ly\":16,
      \"mx\":88,
      \"my\":15
   },
   {
      \"lx\":86,
      \"ly\":17,
      \"mx\":87,
      \"my\":16
   },
   {
      \"lx\":86,
      \"ly\":18,
      \"mx\":86,
      \"my\":17
   },
   {
      \"lx\":85,
      \"ly\":18,
      \"mx\":86,
      \"my\":18
   },
   {
      \"lx\":85,
      \"ly\":19,
      \"mx\":85,
      \"my\":18
   },
   {
      \"lx\":85,
      \"ly\":20,
      \"mx\":85,
      \"my\":19
   },
   {
      \"lx\":84,
      \"ly\":20,
      \"mx\":85,
      \"my\":20
   }
]"
```

Comment: Can you post the JSON data you have, and, if possible, an image of what you expect the result to look like?

Comment: Sure, give me a minute...

Comment: Her is the json data and it is just a small X:

Comment: Not seeing it. Add it to the original post.

Comment: json data is too long to post however, I know that it is correct as I can test using another page. All I really want toi know is how to pass this data to the canvas when the page loads.

Comment: added to original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options:

Echo into a javascript variable when you generate the page:

```
echo "<script>var sig = ".$jsonsig.";</script>";
```

or retrieve it after the page has loaded with an AJAX call

(jQuery in your page script, requires a PHP script to return the JSON code)

```
$.getJSON("getmysig.php",function(data) {
// create canvas here
});
```

Comment: This sounds promising! Mike, if I echo it as you describe, what is the code to grap this var and put it into the canvas?

Comment: also, I am redirecting to different pages depending on security levels after I have got the data with PHP. This would effect the echo wouldn't it?

Comment: I don't know - it depends on how your data is structured. It looks like a set of XY data points, but I can't tell whether that's a filled shape, open shape, or whatever. I have to say, this looks like it will get very heavy on data if your signature becomes more complex.

Comment: On redirection: I can't really comment without a good understanding of how your application is structure. You should be able to echo into any page: exactly how and when you do that depends on your page structure.

Comment: Yes, the data can get quite big. I think I am going to try and save it to a file on the server and get it from there. It is just so strange: I have another page where I can create a signature and save it to the DB and if I open this in a separate browser tab and create the signature, I can get it back in the first page with a button click. ?? I am so confused with this stuff now!

Comment: Thanks for your help though Mike. I do appreciate it!

Comment: You're welcome. Someone has edited your JSON into a more readable form. Is this pixel by pixel data? If so, this really isn't the way to do this. You should really save an image (.PNG, .GIF, whatever) to the server disk and serve it from there. Store the image name in the database, certainly. No canvas, no JSON, less trouble and less data!

Comment: I think you are correct and it is what I was going to do from the start but I have no idea how to save the signature as a PNG or whatever to the server. I am very new at this as I am sure you have guessed.

Comment: Well, I am using code written by Thomas Bradley and I have just found examples of converting the json to an image here: http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-to-image/

Comment: Mike, having found this and reading your comments, I am certain that an image stored on the server is the way to go. Thanks again!

Comment: How are you capturing the signature data now?

Comment: Thomas Bradley's script generates json data once you have signed the canvas and clicked a submit button in a form whicxh then gets into PHP and I get the data with $_POST['output'];

Comment: OK Mike, I have to go now but thanks again for all your input. I think I am going to get this working as I wish now by using an image instead of the raw json data. It just makes so much sense. Cheers for now.